# CFDOCUMENT times out on generating simple PDF (ColdFusion)

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, timeout

I am generating very simple PDF document with Logo image in ColdFusion. I am receiving this error.

**The content of this document process takes more than 60000 milliseconds to process.**

```
 <cfdocument name="pdfdoc" margintop="1.5"  format="pdf" pageheight="15" pagetype="custom" pagewidth="11"  fontEmbed="yes" >
            <cfif Fee_Agreement_Contact_Name EQ "">
                <cfset Fee_Agreement_Contact_Name = QFeeAgreement.Contact_Full_Name>
            </cfif>
            <cfif Fee_Agreement_Contact_JobTitle EQ "">
                <cfset Fee_Agreement_Contact_JobTitle =  QFeeAgreement.Contact_Job_Title>   
            </cfif> 
            <div style="width: 830px;">#request.Fee_Agreement_Text#</div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div style="margin:15px 0 0 0;">
                <cfif Fee_Agreement_Contact_Name NEQ "">
                    <div style="font-size:14px; font-family: Arial;"><b>Full Name:</b> #Fee_Agreement_Contact_Name#</div>
                </cfif>
                <cfif Fee_Agreement_Contact_JobTitle NEQ "">
                    <div style="font-size:14px; font-family: Arial;"><b>Job Title:</b>  #Fee_Agreement_Contact_JobTitle#</div>
                </cfif>
                <cfif Fee_Agreement_AcceptReject_Date NEQ "">
                    <div style="font-size:14px; font-family: Arial;"><b>Agreement Accepted On:</b> #DateFormat(Fee_Agreement_AcceptReject_Date,"mmm d, yyyy")# at #TimeFormat(Fee_Agreement_AcceptReject_Date, 'hh:mm tt')#</div>
                </cfif>
            </div>
        </cfdocument>
     
        <cfif  request.IndustryID EQ 4 >
            <!--- <cfset image="../../images/sterling_logo.png"> ---><!--- Task 3025, Feb 9, 2015 by omer --->
            <cfset image="../../images/sls_logo_high_resolution.jpg">
            <cfset position = "270,1000">
            <cfimage source="#image#" action="read" name="myWatermark">  
            <cfset ImageScaleToFit(myWatermark,250,100)> 
         <cfelse >
            <cfset myWatermark="../../images/Fep_Exective_Search.png">
            <cfset position = "190,1000">
        </cfif>
        <cfpdf name="pdfdoc" source="pdfdoc" action="addWatermark" foreground="yes" image=#myWatermark# overwrite="yes" position=#position#>
```

How can I fix this issue in the ColdFusion?

Comment: You need to post some code at least. Where is the logo coming from? Local disk or Amazon S3? Can't just imagine why the timeout may be happening. Is this a local dev server or a production server? What version of ColdFusion? What version of the JDK?

Comment: First, isolate the problem.   Start by commenting out everything after `</cfdocument>` and run the page.  If it still times out, comment out everything in that block of code and replace it with some simple text.  Once you get the page to run, start uncommenting code bit by bit until it times out again.

Comment: What is the color palette of the JPG? We've had best success with Adobe-friendly RGB JPGs. I'd also resize it once rather than every time the script is run. (Check fileExists() & compare dates if necessary; faster than resizing during each execution.) Is the image locally hosted? If so, using file:// may be beneficial. Our CF9-2021/Lucee solution has been to switch over entirely to WKHTMLTOPDF for all PDF generation.  We also use GraphicsMagick for all image manipulations (faster, more options & wider format support.)

Comment: And does the user that ColdFusion server is running on have access to that file's location?